# keyup event is not triggered when user enters word in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

There is an existing page in the website which i am modifying. The aspx page contains following elements:

```
<table id="Table1">
<tr>
<td>
<table>
<tr>
<th><div id="div1"><label id="label1"></div></th>
<th><div id="div2"><label id="label2"></div></th>
<th><div id="div3"><label id="label3"></div></th>
<th><div id="div4"><label id="label4"></div></th>
<th><div id="div5"><label id="label5"></div></th>
</tr>
</table>
</table>
```

Now the requirement is to have a textbox in 3rd column header alongwith label; so i added the textbox in:

```
<th><div id="div3"><label id="label3">
<asp:textbox id="description"></div></th>
```

In javascript i added the following code for textbox's keyup event:

```
$(document.ready(function(){
$("#description").keyup(function(event)(){
alert("some message");
});
});
```

When the page is loaded and i type something in texbox, then no alert box is shown. If i remove the textbox from column and keep it outside table. then alert box is shown.
If i try to show the textbox content, then i am getting undefined in the alert box when the page is loaded but if i do the following in $(document.ready():

```
var text= $("<%=description.ClientID%>");
alert(text.value);
```

with this i am getting the value of textbox when page is loaded.

Need help to trigger the keyup for the textbox present inside table.

Comment: runat="server" attribute is present for the elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `class` selector for this instead

```
<th>
<div id="div3">
<label id="label5"></label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="description" runat="server" class="myClass"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</th>
```

**script**

```
$(function () {
        $(".myClass").keyup(function (event) {
            alert("some message");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `clientID`

```
$(function() {
    $("<%=description.ClientID%>").keyup(function(event) {
        alert("some message");
    });
});
```